# How to set the width as undefined in powerpoint textbox

Tags: add-in, powerpoint

I am trying to set the width of a textbox as undefined so it will behave as autofit
in powerPoint 2007 I use the following:

```
shape = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, left, top, 0f, 0f);
```

And it look fine on the slide in pp-2007
But when I open the presentation in pp-2010 I get all the characters of the text wraped under each other.
This is maybe to be expected when you set the width as 0 but it looks fine in pp-2007.
I also use the following but it dose not help:

```
shape.AutoSize = PpAutoSize.ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText;
```

I tried it also like this:

```
shape = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, left, top, float.NaN, 0f);
```

But that only gives me a very long textbox

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable word wrap then PowerPoint will size the text box as required:

```
shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText
shape.TextFrame.WordWrap = msoFalse
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Text"
```

Comment: I thought I did, I do it again regards

Comment: Now I have got It. Thank you for clarifying that for me, regards.